# What should i chose to save my data? Eclipse, android programming

Tags: java, android, eclipse, fileoutputstream

I am new to programming in Eclipse and I want to make a note application in android, where i can click on a button to make a new edit text and then i want to save that edit text by pushing save. What is the best way to save this data? Is it by using Shared Preference or with File Output Stream? What is easiest. And also, how can I program the button to make new edit texts which can be saved afterwards?

One last question, if i want these notes to automatically get the date, so i can recall all the notes for a month how do i do that? what types of method should i use?

I hope you will help me, thanks..

Comment: Save data using sqlite ,  it's easy to use them. To get the time you can use a method available to get system time.

Comment: I recommend the official overview of [Android persistence options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is like a "Chinese Box", composed by more hidden questions... without code, of course!

BTW: use **SQLite**, IMHO is the better one for what you want.
In your main activity, add a "New note" button, wich let you create a new note.
In your "SaveNote" method, add also some code wich take the time when you created the note.

Start with [this official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html).

Comment: I know, but this were the question i had.. ;)
SQLite is not an online service?

Comment: @Niller no, i higly recommend you to see also this guide ;-) : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html